# Angular drag and drop list item copy and modify

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

The problem I have is that I have outsourced the code into separate components based on this code.

[mainCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hpxqe4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

And As long as it's just a list item it works fine, but if I modify the list item like this the code breaks.

```
{
  categoryName: 'name',
  open: true,
  baseCategory: [
    {
      icon: faSquare,
      name: '2.1 Column',
    },
    {
      icon: faSquare,
      name: '2.2 Column',
    },
  ],
}
```

In my case, the baseCategory can be dragged. However, based on my code, I always run into errors. Unfortunately I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I also don't know how to transform the value of the indented element. Here again, I could give a specific example, how could you write a drag and drop for a finished project? How does it work for them, if you drag a 1x2 row you can drag elements into it? (two cell)
Maybe I'm approaching it wrong, so sorry but I'd try to write something similar to what you can find in the ready-made example link. I hope I get some help.

[ready drag and drop example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drc-angular-page-builder?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

my code:

**parent component html:**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menu">
  <div>
    <ul
      class="menu"
      cdkDropList
      #menuList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="menu"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="childComponent.tableList"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      (cdkDropListExited)="exited($event)"
      (cdkDropListEntered)="entered()"
    >
      <li class="item" *ngFor="let item2 of item.items" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">
        <div class="item" *cdkDragPlaceholder>
          <a>{{ item2.title }}</a>
        </div>
        <a>{{ item2.title }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </ng-container>
 <app-child #childComponent [menu]="menu" (tableListElement)="updateListElem($event)"> 
</app-child>
```

**parent ts:**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<IMenu[]>): void {
if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
  copyArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
} else {
  moveItemInArray(
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
 }
}

exited(event: CdkDragExit): void {
 let currentIdx: number;

 console.log(event);

 event.container.data.forEach((obj: any) => {
   obj.items.forEach((obj: any) => {
     currentIdx = event.container.data.findIndex(
       (f: any) => f.id === obj.id
     );
   })
 })

this.menu.forEach((obj: any) => {
  obj.items.splice(currentIdx + 1, 0, {
    ...event.item.data,
    temp: true,
  })
 })
}

entered(): void {
 this.menu.filter((obj:any) => {
   obj.items = obj.items.filter((obj2: any) => !obj2.temp)
 })
}

updateListElem(event: any): void {
 // this.menu = event;
}
```

**child components html:**

```
 <div
class="table"
cdkDropList
#tableList="cdkDropList"
[cdkDropListData]="table"
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <div class="item" [ngClass]="{ 'dashed-border': border }" *ngFor="let item of table" cdkDrag>
        <div class="example-custom-placeholder" [ngClass]="{ 'dashed-border': border }" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
        <p [ngClass]="{ 'dashed-border': border }">{{item.name}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**child ts:**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<IMenu[]>) {
if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
  this.table.splice(event.currentIndex, 0, event.item.data);
} else {
  moveItemInArray(
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );
}

if (event.previousContainer.data) {
  this.menu.forEach(obj => {
    obj.baseCategory = obj.baseCategory.filter((obj2: BaseCategory) => !obj2.temp);
  });
  
  this.tableListElement.emit(this.menu);
 }
}
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.insertBefore

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'context')
```